# Run x86 msi setup on x64 os / platform

Tags: architecture, windows-installer, x86, 64-bit

Is it possible (and recommented) to ship a x86 app only in a x86 msi setup which is executed as x86 app on 64 bit os / cpu?

Answer (score 2):

It is both possible and recommended. If you don't have x64 version, shipping x86 is the only solution available. x64 versions are recommended only for cases where you really use the power of x64 platform, not just recompilation.